# How to compute probabilities of any disjoint event in a σ-field?

Tags: probability

EXERCISE: Let A, B, C be disjoint events in a probability space with

$$ P(A)=0.6, P(B)=0.3, P(C)=0.1. $$

Calculate the probabilities of every event in $\sigma(A,B,C)$.

I started recalling properties of a σ-field and, afterwards, I defined the corresponding $\sigma$-field:

$$σ(A,B,C):=\{0.6,~0.3,~0.1,~1-0.6,~1-0.3,~1-0.1,~0.6+0.3+0.1,~\emptyset \}$$

Am I right? Is this required by the exercise?

I look forward to hearing from you.
Best,

Manuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to determine what events are in the sigma field $\sigma(A,B,C)$. What you wrote for the sigma field is just a list of probabilities (and the empty set), but you want a list of **events**. For starters you know the events $A,B,C$ are all in this sigma field. Their complements $A^c, B^c, C^c$ must be as well. Next we need countable unions and intersections of these events. Adding those is not enough, because we still need countable unions and intersections involving the events we just added. Keep adding those unions and intersections to the sigma field. When you think you are done, you can check that you have the entire sigma field as follows:

- check that the complement of each event in the sigma field is in the sigma field
- given any countable collection of events in the sigma field, check that their union and intersection are both in the sigma field

The fact that $A,B,C$ are disjoint and their probabilities sum to $1$ is important for determining the sigma algebra $\sigma(A,B,C)$. For instance, $A\cup B\cup C$ must encompass the entire state space (except possibly an event of probability zero, but I think it is safe to ignore any such event), and (for example) $A \cap B$ must be empty as $A,B$ are disjoint. These sorts of observations will help you simplify your list of events in $\sigma(A,B,C)$.

Once you have a list of events in the sigma field, you need to determine their probabilities. Again, you will need the fact that $A,B,C$ are disjoint and their probabilities sum to $1$. Remember that for disjoint events $A_1,A_2$, we have $P(A_1 \cup A_2)=P(A_1)+P(A_2)$.

Comment: As far as the question is formulated, probably the entire state space is $A\cup B\cup C$ and as the sets are discount, the problem is equivalent to one with 3 singletons. Thus it is known that the cardinality of the sigma algebra is $2^3=8$. It therefore suffices to find 8 different elements.

Comment: I agree, it is probably safe to assume that $A\cup B \cup C$ is the entire state space. That is a good point that the sigma algebra should have $8$ elements.